# Azure function-Timer unscheduledInvocationReason

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to diagnose this error when my timer function runs. I have not found much help on this on google search

UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2019-06-13T15:13:00.0000000-07:00

It seems like the process just stops when this error comes.

Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: IsPastDue is a flag set when the timer is overdue, as Haitham Shaddad's answer below describes. It shouldn't halt further timer executions, though. Could you post your issue to the Functions GitHub for tracking and provide the following information for the product team to investigate: timeframe, function app name, function name(s), region, invocation ID(s). Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old but I had a similar issue and found out that I was on free plan which stops keeping your function app "alive" hence the timer function will not execute. I have to access it via azure and then magically my timer functions execute.

Comment: Does anyone know if this error happens if the timertrigger previous run exceeds the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

The IsPastDue flag is passed to your azure function to indicate if the timer was overdue or not. A timer function can run late in some scenarios like the app service was restarted, in this case it is still invoked but the IsPastDue flag will be set to true to give your function a chance to react.

These links are helpful

[Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)

Also, it seems that it was an issue and it is submitted on github but that was on 2017

[TimerTrigger can miss IsPastDue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/194)

Answer (score 1):

Got this error locally.

[image]

> [2021-06-16T14:58:22.779Z] Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger'
> (Reason='Timer fired at 2021-06-16T16:58:22.7688953+02:00',
> Id=adbaee54-8a3e-4983-a7e4-a73f69153e5e) [2021-06-16T14:58:22.780Z]
> Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue,
> OriginalSchedule: 2021-06-16T16:37:00.0000000+02:00
> [2021-06-16T14:59:22.614Z] Starting worker process failed
> [2021-06-16T14:59:22.615Z] The operation has timed out.

Solved by clearing Blob Emulator locally:

```
delete
  FROM [AzureStorageEmulatorDb510].[dbo].[Blob]
```

[image]

Comment: My storage is in azure, I cleaned the `azure-webjobs-hosts` container and restarted.  Got a bunch of errors, re-restared and voilà it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Using Maxime's answer, I looked in my Azure storage container under azure-webjobs-hosts/timers/[host-id] and I noticed that there was another function app in that folder causing a host ID collision. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#host-id-considerations) by Microsoft, the first 32 characters of the function app were not unique between the two apps. I solved it by adding an AzureFunctionsWebHost_hostid config setting to each app as suggested by Microsoft in the link above.