# Azure function issue: Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule:

Tags: azure-functions

We have an Azure Function app with 4 functions, including a timer trigger. Although it is originally scheduled to run every 4 hours, it is unexpectedly triggering every 2 to 3 minutes due to the “UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue.” Additionally, this function makes an external API call to pull data into the system.

I tried disabling, enabling, restarting, and deleting and redeploying the function, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

- The IsPastDue flag passes to the azure function to warn if the timer was overdue.
- Sometimes, a timer function can run late, in this case it is still invoked but later than scheduled or a function app `restart` might cause an invocation to be missed.
- Then `IsPastDue` flag will be set to true to give your function a chance to react.

Use below code to check if `IsPastDue` flag is true:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
       
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger was delayed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
    else
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

- **To resolve this error, clean the `azure-webjobs-hosts` container and restart the function.**
- Also check the function logs for the error details in the Application Insights of Function App:

[image]

- As mentioned in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126499) answer, it could also be due to having multiple functions, create a separate function app for the Timer Trigger function.